# How to set value to 0 if input isn´t type in? c++

Tags: c++

hi i am sorry if this is a silly question but i am new to programming. I can´t find how to give a value 0 to a variable unless the input says different. Looks something like this

```
int main() {
    // weekly accountability
    std::cout << " ...";
    std::cout << " Please write down the numbers\n";
    double a2;
    double b2;
    double c3;
    std::cin >> a2 >> b2 >> c3;
    "!\n";
    double x = 0.66;
    double sum2 =a2 + b2 +c3;
    std::cout << " Great! so your results were " << sum2 * x<< "";
}
```

when i run it if i only type 2 numbers and press enter it doesn´t show the output cause it waits for me to add the 3rd value. I want to be able to put between 1 and 3 numbers, but i want the program to give a value of 0 if i didn´t input the value.

Comment: So you want to type 1 to 3 numbers, and when you press enter, you'd like to see the result?

Comment: When you want line-oriented input, I think it works much better to use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) rather than stream extraction. Then you can use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to do the conversion.

Comment: What is `"!\n"` supposed to do?

Comment: @cigien yep that´s right, actually i want to type between 1 and like 15 numbers but i am just learning and i wanted to do it just using operators and int/double/string variables

Comment: @FredLarson You can still use stream extraction with line-oriented input.  Just read a line first and then put it into a `std::istringstream`, then you can extract from that.

Comment: If you're taking a sequence of numbers, it's also common to base the end on EOF. The user can type in their EOF key when done and it works fine with piped or redirected input, and it doesn't force one number per line when separating them by spaces is often more convenient to enter should someone be running the program many times.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know how many numbers are being entered, you should read the entire line first, and then extract numbers from that line as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // weekly accountability
    std::cout << " ... Please write down the numbers\n";

    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream iss(line);

    double num, sum = 0.0;
    while (line >> num) {
        sum += num;
    }

    double x = 0.66;
    std::cout << " Great! so your results were " << sum * x;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you can just keep reading from `std::cin` directly until the user types in their platform's EOF sequence (or enters bad input), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // weekly accountability
    std::cout << " ... Please write down the numbers\n";

    double num, sum = 0.0;
    while (std::cin >> num) {
        sum += num;
    }

    double x = 0.66;
    std::cout << " Great! so your results were " << sum * x;

    return 0;
}
```